# Tomcat performance degradation with large VM Memory space

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, jvm

Are there any reasons why Tomcat shouldn't run in a JVM with huge VM memory? Do you know any numbers or whatever reasons why it should be advisable to have multiple tomcat instances on the same host instead of one only?

In my opinion this depends on the performance of the GC used. But maybe there are other reasons why tomcat should live in a VM with not too much memory assigned. Are there any reasons why it would be advisable to have multiple tomcat instances on the same host only to reduce memory of the single vms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ideas related to advantage of multiple servers/smaller heap vs a single one/huge heap:

1. You will have a single point of failure if you use a single machine - you may have Tomcat bugs or some bugs in the deployed applications that requires restarting the JVM, (a several seconds/minutes downtime).
2. A major gargabe collection will take more time on a huge heap compared with a smaller one.

Comment: Is this still true (2.) for the new G1 GC?

Comment: @lewap, if G1 needs to do a full GC+compaction it will be even slower but the main idea is that it should not be doing  so.